# Why is Externalizer allowing null resource resolver?

Tags: aem

As per [javadocs](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/commons/Externalizer.html), Externalizer API allows null resource resolver argument. What is the purpose of allowing null? Externalizer should resolve the given path against resource mapping and return resolved URL. And if resource resolver is null, this purpose is defeated right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decompiled **com.day.cq.commons.impl.ExternalizerImpl.class** to see why it was optional. The reason the resolver would be necessary is to reverse the resolution mappings for the external URI. If you don't specify a resource resolver or request, the code will just default to the path provided without trying to reverse the resolved path.

```
URI mapped = URI.create(resolver != null ? resolver.map(path) : path);
```

So as an example you could have a mapping from **/content** to **/content/geometrixx/en**. Passing in the resolver and a path of **/content/geometrixx/en** would result in **/content**.  If you wanted to make sure it was always **/content/geometrixx/en** pass null for the resource resolver.